# How do I search for .exe files

Tags: perl

Do you guys have an idea on how to search or list down .exe files on the server
I am currently using (or maybe place it in an array)?
I will use this command in my Perl program. Assuming that my program  is also located on the said server. 
My OS is Linux - Ubuntu if that even matters, just in case. Working in CLI here. =)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you actually want to accomplish? Linux does not use ".exe" files, that's a Windows thing.

Comment: My perl program aims to delete a specific .exe files.. for example, all "sampleFile.exe" with different versions must be deleted when the program is executed, coz i only need the latest version. Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure if you will be able to read specific version metadata of a windows executable while running in a linux session. Wouldn't this task be easier on a windows box?

Comment: @Suezy Not with the information you have provided.  How do you intend to determine the version of the file?  Is it based on the directory?  Is there some version string inside the file.  There are also a host of other questions that are raised, such as why a Window's executable is on a Linux box.

Comment: Maybe the executables are there because of Wine?

Comment: Okay.. but first things first is i need to know how to locate an exe file, then i'll figure out the other ways. Coz i'll probably start having the file-to-delete as a parameter instead. I need it in a program because the files are in max sizes.

Comment: @Chas Actually, there are some versions in the string inside the file, and I have all the files that are needed to be removed. I'm remotely working in a LINUX box. Do you mean it is only possible in Windows?

Comment: okay..so THANKS everyone! very much appreciated.. This is a good place for beginners like me. =)

Comment: I have my doubts about that. You picked the worst answer possible. Granted it's not that bad an answer, but you will end up with a horrible mess of Perl code that would have been easier to do in a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll probably be shot down for suggesting this, but you don't have to use modules for a simple task. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
@array = `find ~ -name '*.exe' -print`;
foreach (@array) {
    print;
}
```

Of course, it will need to have some tweaking for your particular choice of starting directory (here, I used ~ for the home directory)

EDIT: Maybe I should have said *until you get the modules installed*

Comment: nice..this is what I'm "looking" for..lol. just a simple command.. just like mirod's.. =)

Comment: oh...thanks anyway! =) next time I'll figure it out. *a newbie* ;D

Comment: Thanks Suezy. I'm poking my tongue out at whoever downvoted me.

Comment: Just got downvoted again, several months after the question was posted. It is still the accepted answer, see Suezy's comment above.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, It is not clear whether you want '*.exe' files, or executable files.
You can use File::Find::Rule to find all executable files.

```
  my @exe= File::Find::Rule->executable->in( '/');     # all executable files  
  my @exe= File::Find::Rule->name( '*.exe')->in( '/'); # all .exe files
```

If you are looking for executable files, you (the user running the script) need to be able to execute the file, so you probably need to run the script as root.

It might take a long time to run to.

If you are looking for .exe files, chances are that your disk is already indexed by `locate`. So this would be much faster:

```
  my @exe= `locate \.exe | grep '\.exe$'`
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to find every file under a specified directory that has a `.exe` suffix:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use File::Spec;
use IO::Handle;

die "Usage: $0 startdir\n"
    unless scalar @ARGV == 1;
my $startdir = shift @ARGV;

my @stack;

sub process_file($) {
    my $file = shift;
    print $file
        if $file =~ /\.exe$/io;
}

sub process_dir($) {
    my $dir = shift;
    my $dh = new IO::Handle;
    opendir $dh, $dir or
        die "Cannot open $dir: $!\n";
    while(defined(my $cont = readdir($dh))) {
        next
            if $cont eq '.' || $cont eq '..';
        my $fullpath = File::Spec->catfile($dir, $cont);
        if(-d $fullpath) {
            push @stack, $fullpath
                if -r $fullpath;
        } elsif(-f $fullpath) {
            process_file($fullpath);
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}

if(-f $startdir) {
    process_file($startdir);
} elsif(-d $startdir) {
    @stack = ($startdir);
    while(scalar(@stack)) {
        process_dir(shift(@stack));
    }
} else {
    die "$startdir is not a file or directory\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to try this one, but needs to install the modules first. =)

Comment: You could take a coderef as the second param of process_dir so that you can reuse the process_dir.

Comment: @Suezy - This program uses only modules from Perl's core distribution, meaning if you have Perl you should have those two modules (and more) installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find).

Alternatively, if you can come up with a command line to the *nix `file` command, you can use `find2perl` to convert that command line to a Perl snippet.

Answer (score 0):

to get recursively use

```
use File::Find;
##cal the function by sending your search dir and type of the file
my @exe_files = &get_files("define root directory" , ".exe");

##now in @exe_files will have all .exe files

sub get_files() {
    my ($location,$type) = @_;
    my @file_list;
    if (defined $type) {
        find (sub { my $str = $File::Find::name;
            if($str =~ m/$type/g   ) {  
                push @file_list, $File::Find::name ;            
            } 
        }, $location);
    } else {
        find (sub {push @file_list, $File::Find::name }, $location);
    }
    return (@file_list);    
}
```